# Why is a named function not working when the unnamed was?

Tags: javascript

I had this code:

```
$('#testsPane').live("click", function() {//if the secondary ui nav tests is 

selected

//Displays the test list

var listOfTests = "";

   var subjects = [];
   var tests= [];
   var titles = [];

   var keysplit;
   var testSubj;

   var key, value;
   for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
       key = localStorage.key(i);
       value = localStorage.getItem(key);

       keysplit = key.split(".");


       tests.push(value);
       titles.push(keysplit[0]);
       subjects.push(keysplit[keysplit.length-1]);




}


for(var i=0; i < tests.length; i++) {

    listOfTests += '<div class="testDisplayBox"><div 

class="subjColorBar"></div><div class="testListIndiContain"><span 

class="testListTitle">' + titles[titles.length-(i+1)] + '</span><span> in 

</span><span class="testListSubj">' + subjects[subjects.length-(i+1)] + 

'</span></div><div class="testListTags"><span 

class="specTags">quiz</span></div></div>';

}

    var testsDashboard = '<div id="testsList">' + listOfTests + '</div>';

$('#selectedPane').append(testsDashboard);//adds the html to the pane to make it 

into the tests dashboard

})
```

The above code worked but I wanted to reuse some of it so I put it into a function. When I did that it did not work. Any idea why? The code below is with using a named function.

```
function grabTestList() {//Displays the test list

   var keysplit;
   var testSubj;
   var key, value;
   for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
       key = localStorage.key(i);
       value = localStorage.getItem(key);

       keysplit = key.split(".");


       tests.push(value);
       titles.push(keysplit[0]);
       subjects.push(keysplit[keysplit.length-1]);

}}
$('#testsPane').live("click", function() {//if the secondary ui nav tests is selected

grabTestList();

   var listOfTests = "";
       var subjects = [];
       var tests= [];
       var titles = [];  

for(var i=0; i < tests.length; i++) {

    listOfTests += '<div class="testDisplayBox"><div class="subjColorBar"></div><div class="testListIndiContain"><span class="testListTitle">' + titles[titles.length-

(i+1)] + '</span><span> in </span><span class="testListSubj">' + subjects[subjects.length-(i+1)] + '</span></div><div class="testListTags"><span 

class="specTags">quiz</span></div></div>';

}

    var testsDashboard = '<div id="testsList">' + listOfTests + '</div>';

$('#selectedPane').append(testsDashboard);//adds the html to the pane to make it into the tests dashboard
})
```

Comment: Please format/indent your code...what you've posted is really unreadable, it'll save you a **lot** of time overall, and make it more readable for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are defining variables in the context of the anonymous function which are unknown to the named function. Pass them to `grabTestList` so the `.push` methods can mutate those arrays.

```
function grabTestList(tests, titles, subjects) {
    // manipulate tests/titles/subjects
}

$('blah').live('click', function() {
    var tests = [], titles = [], subjects = [];

    grabTestList( tests, titles, subjects );

    // since tests, titles, and subjects are mutated by the function, you can just loop through them here.


})
```

**DEMO:**

Here's a sample version which you can base your code on: http://jsfiddle.net/JLK6N/2/

updated with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/JLK6N/3/

Remember that objects are passed by reference, arrays are objects, and methods like `.push` are mutator methods.

Comment: wow the formatting is so poor I completely missed how he's using things, +1